# Ansible: 'ansible.builtin.unarchive' how to get file path of extracted directory?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that runs to upgrade a service when a new version is available. I can `unarchive` the directory, but I cannot find a way to `register` that directory file path so I can then pass it to the `ansible.builtin.copy` module to send to the correct directory.

The issue is the unarchiving names the directory according the version number, I then have to rename it to copy it to the correct directory in order to get the service to work. I have tried:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for upgrade-sabnzbd
- name: Get URL of latest sabnzbd
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest
    body_format: json
    return_content: true
    remote_src: yes
  register: json_response

- name: Create fact URL called "download_url"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    download_url: "{{ (json_response.json.assets | selectattr('browser_download_url', 'search', 'src.tar.gz') | list | first).browser_download_url }}"

- name: Download sabnzbd tarball
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: "{{ download_url }}"
    dest: /tmp
  register: sabnzbd_tarball

- name: Unarchive sabnzbd tarball
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: "{{ sabnzbd_tarball.dest }}"
    dest: /tmp
    list_files: yes
  register: sabnzbd_dir

- name: Print the generated directory
  debug:
    msg: "{{ sabnzbd_dir.files[0].split('/')[0] }}"

- name: Copy new folder to replace exisiting
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    #src: "{{ sabnzbd_dir.dest }}"
    src: "{{ sabnzbd_dir }}"
    dest: /opt/sabnzbd
    owner: "{{ media_user }}"
    group: "{{ media_user }}"

- name: Reload the sabnzbd systemd file
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: sabnzbd
    state: restarted
```

Where `sabnzbd_tarball.dest` comes from another play that works just fine. I have printed that `var` to stdout and it is correct. I cannot get `sabnzbd_dir` to work though. I can get the top directory name with `sabnzbd_dir.files[0].split('/')[0]`, but I need the file path.

Comment: /tmp/SABnzbd-4.0.1 is the content of sabnzbd_tarball.dest

Answer (score 0):

> *The issue is the unarchiving names the directory according the version number, I then have to rename it to copy it to the correct directory in order to get the service to work.*

This is not necessary if using the solution from [unarchive module in Ansible ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716921/266568)? It would simplify a lot, prevent unnecessary multiple disk operations, and you can do almost all in 2-3 task instead of 5-7.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get latest version info of SABnzbd
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest
      body_format: json
      return_content: true
      remote_src: yes
    register: response

  - name: Unarchive SABnzbd tarball
    ansible.builtin.unarchive:
      src: "https://github.com/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/download/{{ response.json.tag_name }}/SABnzbd-{{ response.json.tag_name }}-src.tar.gz"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/SABnzbd"
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      extra_opts: [--strip-components=1, --overwrite]
      remote_src: true
    notify: Stop SABnzbd
```

Furthermore it is recommended to use [`pip` module – Manages Python library dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) to

```yaml
  - name: Install specified python requirements
    ansible.builtin.pip:
      requirements: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/SABnzbd/requirements.txt
    notify: Restart SABnzbd
```

like in there shown [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html#examples).

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to extract without first directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365990/266568)
- [What does `--strip-components` mean in `tar`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575121/266568)

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

```
# tasks file for upgrade-sabnzbd
- name: Get URL of latest sabnzbd
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest
    body_format: json
    return_content: true
    remote_src: yes
  register: json_response

- name: Create fact URL called "download_url"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    download_url: "{{ (json_response.json.assets | selectattr('browser_download_url', 'search', 'src.tar.gz') | list | first).browser_download_url }}"

- name: Unarchive sabnzbd tarball
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: "{{ download_url }}"
    dest: /tmp
    remote_src: yes
    list_files: yes
  register: sabnzbd_dir

- name: Copy new folder to replace exisiting
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ sabnzbd_dir.dest }}/{{ sabnzbd_dir.files[0].split('/')[0] }}"
    dest: /opt/sabnzbd
    owner: "{{ media_user }}"
    group: "{{ media_user }}"
  notify: Stop sabnzbd

- name: Get sabnzbd requirements via pip
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    chdir: /opt/sabnzbd
  notify: Restart sabnzbd
```